# Emacs magit chinese file name displayed as as /320/320/322 in Windows?

Tags: emacs, configure, magit, gbk

My magit use git with cygwin, and my default coding is gbk. 
I tried to modify the .git/config, but not work.

```
   [core]
        quotepath = false  
    [gui]
        encoding = gbk
    [i18n]
        commitencoding = gbk
        logoutputencoding = gbk
    [svn]
        pathnameencoding = gbk
```

Some one said set this in /etc/profile, not work too.

```
export LESSCHARSET=utf-8
```

So where shall I fix this problem, the .emacs, enviroment variables or .git/config?